# Sum of similiar columns for each row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like below

```
doctor_id    forename surname email           ...
 1           jon      doe     jon@doe.com     ...
 2           john     dove    john@dove.com   ...
 3           jane     dane    jane@dane.com   ...
 4           foo      bar     foo@bar.com     ...
 5           bar      foo     bar@foo.com     ...
```

Please consider that my table has about 10 more columns.

I have set of data (forename = "jon", surname="doe", email="foo@bar.com", etc.)

I want to check each row for number of columns that have same value as columns in set of data

```
doctor_id    forename surname email           ...   similiarities
 1           jon      doe     jon@doe.com     ...   2
 2           john     dove    john@dove.com   ...   0
 3           jane     dane    jane@dane.com   ...   0
 4           foo      bar     foo@bar.com     ...   1
 5           bar      foo     bar@foo.com     ...   0
```

and choose only those rows with number of similiarities greater than 3.

Comment: What? Please explain how you got to this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.*,
       ((case when forename = 'jon' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when surname = 'doe' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when email = 'foo@bar.com' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as similarities
from t;
```